# Linked Server to Analysis Services

Tags: sql-server, ssas, business-intelligence

After defining Linked Server on SQL Server 2016 (13.0.1711.0):

```
EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedserver @server = N'CUBELINKEDSERVER', @srvproduct=N'MSOLAP', @provider=N'MSOLAP', @datasrc=N'POWER', @catalog=N'Model'
 /* For security reasons the linked server remote logins password is changed with ######## */
EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedsrvlogin @rmtsrvname=N'CUBELINKEDSERVER',@useself=N'False',@locallogin=NULL,@rmtuser=NULL,@rmtpassword=NULL
```

and using query from http://www.purplefrogsystems.com/blog/2010/09/olap-cube-documentation-in-ssrs-part-1/:

```
SELECT *
FROM OPENQUERY(CubeLinkedServer,
   'SELECT *
    FROM $SYSTEM.MDSCHEMA_MEASUREGROUP_DIMENSIONS') mgd
INNER JOIN OPENQUERY(CubeLinkedServer,
   'SELECT *
    FROM $SYSTEM.MDSCHEMA_MEASUREGROUPS') mg
ON mgd.XXX = mg.XXX
```

I get error:

> Msg 7354, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 The OLE DB provider "MSOLAP" for
>   linked server "CubeLinkedServer" supplied invalid metadata for column
>   "DIMENSION_PATH". The data type is not supported.

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/d8375abc-d845-407e-9bc4-35bfed341e66/retrieving-metadata-information-with-openrowset-from-mdschemameasuregroupdimensions?forum=sqlanalysisservices)  tells that this type is not supported..

> The problem is that the DIMENSION_PATH column is a complex type. If you run the DMV query in SSMS you will see that the column comes back with a + sign. If you don't particularly need that column you can just specify an explicit column list that does not include it.

```
SELECT a.*
FROM OPENQUERY('MSOLAP','
select
[CATALOG_NAME]
,[SCHEMA_NAME]
,[CUBE_NAME]
,[MEASUREGROUP_NAME]
,[MEASUREGROUP_CARDINALITY]
,[DIMENSION_UNIQUE_NAME]
,[DIMENSION_CARDINALITY]
,[DIMENSION_IS_VISIBLE]
,[DIMENSION_IS_FACT_DIMENSION]
--,DIMENSION_PATH
,[DIMENSION_GRANULARITY]
from
$system.MDSCHEMA_MEASUREGROUP_DIMENSIONS' ) a
```

Comment: I don't think it is supported,attached thread says to use CLR